# Ubuntu 11.10 x64 and AMD Processor slow performance

Tags: 11.10, performance

I'm having a problem with the last distributive of Ubuntu. The problem is that with an Intel DualCore E7500, 4GB of RAM DDR3-1600 and x32 bits type of OS with PAE enabled, I have not met performance issues, but when I have switched to AMD Athlon X2 245, 4GB of RAM DDR3-1600 and x64 bits type of OS, after this performance fell. Even at startup of Ubuntu without any active process, GUI is slow. I have disabled Detect Refresh Rate, Sync to V Blank in Compiz, but but without any success. It's the problem really in x64 version of Ubuntu or the problem is the Processor?

1) glxinfo | grep -i direct

direct rendering: Yes
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,

2) sudo lspci | grep VGA

01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc 760G [Radeon 3000]

Comment: I guess from what you ask, that you're talking about 2 different computers, please could you provide more information on graphic cards, etc?

Comment: The graphic card is integrated on both, on AMD PC is ATI Radeon 3000, on Intel I just don't remember, I guess Intel 3000 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that You should see Your mainboard manual, and turn on/off something in BIOS. That is my guess. I prefer intel processors, but the truth is that the processor type should not infuence efficiency in the way You described.

Did You try new config with other OS?

Comment: Yes, I prefer to Intel, but at office, wasn't my choise. No, I didn't tried other os, or the 32 bit type of it, only Ubuntu x64

Comment: Does Your graphic card works? Did You install drivers? If You have, then which ones? Can You give an output of: following commands: glxinfo | grep -i direct   (requires mesa-utils installed) and sudo lspci | grep VGA

Comment: Yes, it works, now I'm using it, with an 240W Philips monitor. I have installed AMD Catalyst Control Center last version for Ubuntu 11.10. The output is in first post, I have edited it.

Comment: Ok, in my opinion now You should take a look on Your BIOS settings. But be careful if changing anything!

Comment: Well, I looked up in there, but didn't find anything specific, I'll look again.

Comment: It is hard to say what should You look for, because all mainboards have really different settings set. But chceck if RAM has proper frequency and voltage, check Your CPUs and other components temperature

Comment: I checked, the CPU temperature is under 30C, the mainboard as well. Frequency of RAM, timings and voltage is default. I came up with the idea to try Ubuntu 11.10 x32 from FlashDrive, and it runs faster, I will try to reinstall the system as soon as possible to try it on HDD.

Comment: that is a good idea. I use Ubuntu Lucid x64 on PC quite similar to Yours and it works very well

Comment: Maybe is all about new version of kernel 3, or unity launcher, who knows.

Comment: Hahaha, I have just removed the f**cking ATI Catalyst Center, installed fglrx-update, and the system like revive :), the problems seams to be in the video drivers

Comment: I'm glad that You can fully enjoy Your ubuntu now :] Regards